# Map integer values to categories defined by range of integers in second dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I am trying to **map zip_codes of given data frame to regions provided by a second data frame**.
The **regions are defined by a range of integers** (for example, range 1000-1299 is Noord-Holland, 1300-1379 is Flevoland and so on). The data looks like this:

```
df1
  zip_code  state_name
0   7514    None
1   7891    None
2   2681    None
3   7606    None
4   5051    None
5   2611    None
6   4341    None
7   1851    None
8   1861    None
9   2715    None

df2
    zpcd1   zpcd2   region
0   1000    1299    Noord-Holland
1   1300    1379    Flevoland
2   1380    1384    Noord-Holland
3   1390    1393    Utrecht
4   1394    1494    Noord-Holland
5   1396    1496    Utrecht
6   1398    1425    Noord-Holland
7   1426    1427    Utrecht
8   1428    1429    Zuid-Holland
9   1430    2158    Noord-Holland
```

*The duplicates regions are ok, because one region can have different zip code ranges.*

The question is: **How do I map the zip code values in df1 to the ranges defined in df2 in order to assign the region name to that row?**

I tried

```
def region_map(row):
    global df2
    if row['zip_code'] in range(nlreg.zpcd1, nlreg.zpcd2, 1):
        return df2.region

df1['state_name'] = df1.apply(lambda row: region_map(row))
```

but it returns a KeyError: 'zip_code'.
Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I got the result that I was searching for using

```
df2['zip_c_range']=list(zip(df2.zpcd1, df2.zpcd2))
for i,v in tqdm(df1.zip_code.items()):
    for x,z in df2.zip_c_range.items():
        if v in range(*z):
            df1['state_name'][i]=df2.region[x]
```

but I am sure that there is a better solution using lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is the following (nlreg being df2):

```
def region_map(zc):
    return nlreg.loc[(nlreg['zpcd1'] <= zc) & (zc <= nlreg['zpcd2']), 'region']

df1['state_name'] = df1['zip_code'].apply(lambda z: region_map(z))
```

Comment: Your KeyError comes from the fact that you apply your function on the wrong axis. You could fix it with `df1.apply(lambda row: region_map(row), axis=1)` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But after giving it a try, even when the code runs ok, doesn't seems to work as I want. The vast majority of cells are labeled as NaN. I got better results with 
`nlreg['zip_c_range']=list(zip(nlreg.zpcd1, nlreg.zpcd2))`
`for i,v in tqdm(df1.zip_code.items()):
    for x,z in nlreg.zip_c_range.items():
        if v in range(*z):
            df1['state_name'][i]=nlreg.region[x]`

Comment: How does your result differ from mine? I get exactly the same output based on your example. You're computing the same thing in a more convoluted way...